# Can a single wallet have multiple addresses, that can be used to distinguish payments?

Tags: wallet, dogecoin, cryptofinance

If I have a single Dogecoin wallet, can I create multiple addresses for that wallet such that I can identify which payments were sent to which address?

For example:

```
1 Dogecoin Wallet with balance 0
3 addresses
A payment of 5 Doge is sent to address 1
A payment of 10 Doge is sent to address 2
A payment of 15 Doge is sent to address 3
The Dogecoin wallet now has a balance of 30 Doge
When I look at the Wallet, I know the payment of 5 Doge was made to address 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use software that supports BIP32 hierarchical deterministic wallets like Electrum.  You will then be able to have one seed with unlimited addresses.  You should only use an address once, so give a different address out each time you want to receive a payment.  This will improve privacy too as people who pay you wont be able to see other transactions you received.

Comment: Thanks - but will I know who made a payment to what address?

Comment: By giving out each address only to one counterparty, you can use them as invoices to identify who paid you: the party that you gave the address to.

Comment: You can also label each address to make the invoicing easier.  You can give your friend one address for item #1 and a second one for item #2.  You will then be able to keep track of what has been repaid by checking if funds have been sent to that address yet

Comment: Thanks @Brandon and Murch - this is exactly what I wanted to know, and the labelling will make this a lot easier.

Comment: Okay so having a look and I'm not having much looking finding something that clearly meets my reqs. I need a command-line Dogecoin BIP32 wallet (I can find a lot of Bitcoin ones)? Any recommendations?

Comment: @cardycakes, Doge is kinda a meme.  You won't find good support for it, but I think the reference implementation can do what you want. https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin